# Question on gcc compiler commands

Tags: c, gcc

I had to compile a small little C program using the following;

gcc sine.c -o sine -lm

I needed the "-lm" because the program included the math.h.

In looking this up under compiler commands man shows it a either -llibrary or -l library.

I could not find any information on what other libraries.  Apparently -lm is needed for math.h
what other library commands might be needed.

Thanks

Comment: You need the libraries you need. There is an almost infinite number of them that you use as your application requires.

Comment: It is worth noting that the library picked up by `-lfoo` is actually `libfoo.so`. The portion of the c standard library that is included with `math.h` is kept in `libm` rather than in `libc`. Presumably there are historical reasons for this, but I couldn't say what they are.

Answer (score 5):

`-lm` means to link the "m" library, which as you said contains math stuff. If you need other libraries for your code, your documentation for those functions will show that.

Comment: Technically it means to *link* the "m" library, not load

Comment: Well load first, then link it :)

Answer (score -1):

If it links without errors, you don't need anything anything else. In fact you don't even need to specify -lm, as it and the standard C library are linked automatically.

Comment: gcc takes the idiosyncratic approach to the maths library - it leads to lots and lots of fun when students do their first gcc practical.

Comment: The math library is _not_ linked automatically. Exactly which operations are in libm, however, depend on the OS and CPU architecture.

Comment: Indeed - and sometimes you need to add `-lmx` as well to get some of the less frequently used math functions, e.g. `log2f`.